# How do I narrow a value to *not* be undefined?

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

Right now I have this code which works...

```
(err, resp) => {
  if (resp) {
    if (resp.missing) {
      resolve(new CacheListFetch.Miss());
    } else if (resp.found) {
      resolve(new CacheListFetch.Hit(resp.found.values));
    } else {
      resolve(new CacheListFetch.Error(cacheServiceErrorMapper(err)));
    }
  } else {
    resolve(new CacheListFetch.Error(cacheServiceErrorMapper(err)));
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get rid of that redundant error clause. I tried this...

```
(err, resp) => {
  switch (true) {
    case typeof resp === 'undefined':
    default:
      resolve(new CacheListFetch.Error(cacheServiceErrorMapper(err)));
      break;
    case resp.missing instanceof
      cache_client._ListFetchResponse._Missing:
      resolve(new CacheListFetch.Miss());
      break;
    case resp.found instanceof cache_client._ListFetchResponse._Found:
      resolve(new CacheListFetch.Hit(resp.found.values));
      break;
  }
}
```

eslint keeps saying `resp` is possibly undefined, yet that's not possible.

```
src/internal/cache-client.ts:303:18 - error TS18048: 'resp' is possibly 'undefined'.

303             case resp.missing instanceof
                     ~~~~

src/internal/cache-client.ts:307:18 - error TS18048: 'resp' is possibly 'undefined'.

307             case resp.found instanceof cache_client._ListFetchResponse._Found:
                     ~~~~

src/internal/cache-client.ts:308:46 - error TS18048: 'resp' is possibly 'undefined'.

308               resolve(new CacheListFetch.Hit(resp.found.values));
                                                 ~~~~
```

How can I DRY up that nested if/else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in your conditions:

```
(err, resp) => {
  if (resp?.missing) {
    resolve(new CacheListFetch.Miss());
  } else if (resp?.found) {
    resolve(new CacheListFetch.Hit(resp.found.values));
  } else {
    resolve(new CacheListFetch.Error(cacheServiceErrorMapper(err)));
  }
}
```

This allows you to test the existence of `resp` and the existence of `resp.missing` in a single statement.

If you end up at `else` it's because:

- `resp` is falsy.
- or `resp` exists and `resp.missing` and `resp.found` are both falsy.

Comment: Interesting! I'd tried that as a `switch` and it didn't work. https://gist.github.com/schwern/a50736ed605341e82a5bb5599c15ecf6

Comment: That's because the type of `a?.b` when a is `undefined` would be `undefined`, not `false`. And typescript doesn't like you comparing `undefined` and `true` directly. You could do `!!(resp?.missing)` but that starts to get verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only test the `resp` reference for nullish value. You can check if `resp === null || resp === undefined` and if that doesn´t match up, you can be sure that value will be either an instance of `cache_client._ListFetchResponse._Missing` or `cache_client._ListFetchResponse._Found`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider returning early:

```
(err, resp) => {  
  if (resp?.missing) return resolve(new CacheListFetch.Miss());
   
  if (resp?.found) return resolve(new CacheListFetch.Hit(resp.found.values));

  return resolve(new CacheListFetch.Error(cacheServiceErrorMapper(err)));
}
```